# How to stop Networkx from changing the order of head and tail nodes(u,v) to (v,u) in an edge?

Tags: python, graph, nodes, networkx, edge-list

I've got a simple graph created using networkx.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pprint import pprint

G = nx.Graph()
head_nodes = range(0, 9)
tail_nodes = range(1, 10)
edge_ls = list(zip(head_nodes, tail_nodes))
G.add_nodes_from(range(0, 10))
G.add_edges_from(edge_ls)
pprint(G.nodes())
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

I want to remove the edge between node 0 and 1 and add three new nodes (say node 10,11,12). Then, edges have
to be created between node 0 and 10, 10 and 11, 11 and 2.

I'm using `G.remove_edge(0,1)` to remove the edge between node 0 and 1.

Could someone suggest which function can be used to add  `n` new nodes?

Also, if `n` new nodes are added, will these nodes be numbered automatically?

I intend to do this in a loop, delete an edge that already exists between two nodes and add `n` new nodes and edges connecting these nodes.

EDIT: 
I tried the following to add `n` new edges

```
G = nx.Graph()
head_nodes = range(0, 9)
tail_nodes = range(1, 10)
edge_ls = list(zip(head_nodes, tail_nodes))
G.add_nodes_from(range(0, 10))
G.add_edges_from(edge_ls)

head = 0
tail = 1
G.remove_edge(head, tail)
Nnodes = G.number_of_nodes()
newnodes = [head, Nnodes+1, Nnodes+2, Nnodes+3, tail] # head and tail already exists
newedges = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(newnodes[0:len(newnodes)-1], newnodes[1:len(newnodes)])]
G.add_edges_from(newedges)
pprint(G.edges())
```

Output:

```
EdgeView([(0, 11), (1, 2), (1, 13), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (11, 12), (12, 13)])

Expected Output:
EdgeView([(0, 11), (1, 2), (13, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9), (11, 12), (12, 13)])
```

I'm not sure why the edge that was added in the order (13,1)(head, tail) is stored as (1,13). Any suggestion on how to preserve the order of head and tail node while adding a new edge?

EDIT2:
replacing nx.Graph() with nx.OrderedGraph() also doesn't help.

Comment: Hi - a note on asking questions here.  It's easiest for us to answer if you keep to just one question per "question".  Otherwise you end up with a situation like this one where you've asked multiple questions, and only had one of them answered.  You should try to pare down your question and then pose multiple separate questions.  This has the "side effect" of making it easier for others in the future to solve their problems.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

A `Graph` is an undirected graph, where `(1, 13)` and `(13, 1)` mean the same thing, the edges have no 'arrows'.

What you want is a `DiGraph`, meaning a directed graph. See https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/index.html

An `OrderedGraph` is something else - it just means that when you iterate over nodes and edges, they come out in a particular order (similar to lists vs sets).

Comment: The incidence matrix is different when the order of nodes is not preserved.

Comment: @Natasha well if you want, you can use an `OrderedDiGraph`.

Comment: There is a problem with using Digraph for inputs like [lthis](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/cytoscape/blob/master/edge_ls.xlsx). The directed graph that is generated doesn't have the arrows directed from one end to the other end of the graph. Is there any alternate way to preserve the order of nodes in undirected graph?

Comment: "The directed graph that is generated doesn't have the arrows directed from one end to the other end of the graph" I have no idea what that means, or what is special about your sample data. "Is there any alternate way to preserve the order of nodes in undirected graph?" If the graph is undirected then that should mean the order of nodes doesn't matter. I suggest keeping the original edges in a separate data structure you can check, because there's no reason for networkx to remember it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have created a new post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941307/how-to-stop-networkx-from-changing-the-order-of-nodes-from-u-v-to-v-u-in-an)